# aligning text with image to left in css3

Tags: css

Given the following markup

```
<div id="newItems" class="literaltext" >
    <p> <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/32x32.png"  
                   ClientIDMode="Static" />&nbsp;&nbsp; Click
                        <a href="Shareholder Letter Jan 2013_Final.pdf" >here</a> 
                        to read our President's letter to shareholder's for 2013
    </p>
    <br />
    <p> <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/32x32.png"  
                   ClientIDMode="Static" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span >Click
                        <a href="Calc.aspx" >here</a> 
                        to run our <strong>Return on Investment Calculator</strong> to see how the economics of using <span class="green"><b>EnerBurn&reg;</b></span> can work for your fleet.</span>
    </p>
    <br />
    <asp:Literal ID="LiteralWelcome"  runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

and the following css;

```
#newItems {
display: inline-block;

}
#newItems img {
    /*display: block;*/
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#newItems span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

I cannot get the text to the right of the image to align with the image. The image always appears much higher then the text. If i could vertically align the text in the middle of the height in the p tag it would at least look about right. I've tried about 50 variations, this being the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

on the img rule seems to work:

```
#newItems img {
    /*display: block;*/
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hkDzt/)**